# Using background-color on a div containing a footer not working properly

Tags: html, css, background-color

Im trying to set the background colour of a footer/a div containing a footer. However through trying different ways I am only able to get it like so:[Footer miscolouring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90FEY.png) where the purple is the div, yellow is the footer via id tag. This is done by calling an external css file with the code:

```css
footer {}

footer li {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #9400D3;
}

footer nav li {
  background-color: #9400D3;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer nav li a {
  background-color: #9400D3;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

footer p {
  background-color: #9400D3;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

#footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

#footerDiv {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #9400D3;
}
```

```html
<div id="footerDiv">
  <footer id="footer">
    <p>Disclamer: no images used on this site are owned by me.</p>
    <p style="font-family:HOBO;">Copyright:Named Person 2019</p>
    <nav>
      <li>
        <a href="index.php"> Go home </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="products.php"> Product Page </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="faq.php"> FAQ </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.php"> Contact us</a>
      </li>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: yellow color is missing in footer ?

Comment: The position of #footer seems wrong to me, why you use position:absolute?

Comment: remove the explicit height you are defining